# Adding a player to a team only when they are wearing specific armor set?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Looking to have 2 teams on the server,

What would I use to set this up?

*Details/Desire*

**1 team default** *shows nametag *all active players are this automatically

**2 team Ghillie** *hides nametag *all players wearing full GOLDEN ARMOR will be automatically added to this team. Removed when not wearing full gold armor

Edit*
Thank you for answers! Still having trouble though
 Not sure where the specific change areas are for team names *for copy-code answer below and if they should be split between the two? team names are default for no gold armor and ghillie for full gold armor –

Comment: What have you tried already, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I am trying the Commands posted below, and i'm not sure if i'm substituting the correct team names for the placeholder values

Comment: I meant before you asked your question. As mentioned in the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and on the ['Asking' page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it is expected of users with questions to have put some effort into solving their problem before asking others for input.

Comment: Yes testfor armor and add team commands various ones couldnt get it to function at all...

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in a repeating command block:

```
/team join team1 @a[team=!team1,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:golden_boots",Count:1b,Slot:100b},{id:"minecraft:golden_leggings",Count:1b,Slot:101b},{id:"minecraft:golden_chestplate",Count:1b,Slot:102b},{id:"minecraft:golden_helmet",Count:1b,Slot:103b}]}]
```

and run this command in a chain command block attached to the repeating one:

```
/team join team2 @a[team=!team2,nbt=!{Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:golden_boots",Count:1b,Slot:100b},{id:"minecraft:golden_leggings",Count:1b,Slot:101b},{id:"minecraft:golden_chestplate",Count:1b,Slot:102b},{id:"minecraft:golden_helmet",Count:1b,Slot:103b}]}]
```

replace the placeholder team names with your team names and set both command blocks to always active.

Comment: Thank you! having trouble though not sure where the specific change areas are for team names and if they should be split between the two? team names are default for no gold armor and ghillie for full gold armor

Comment: There are two "team1" placeholders in the first command and two "team2" placeholders in the second command. Change those to the names of your teams.

Comment: I get "error no entity found" in the (wearing armor) block

Comment: That means that no player matches the specified criteria. Make sure that you changed both placeholders ("team2") and it should work when you wear the armor.

Comment: Okay getting somewhere, I got the armor team to work, full armor adds to the team however once a player is added it does not seem to want to add them back once armor is off, i want this to only work while wearing full golden armor. if you take 1 piece of it off it currently doesn't remove you from the team.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you. Here is a world download with the working system: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v4appbdhxo8cfto/AABF4bpfSCQhNnJC_QBirDX9a?dl=0 I set up two teams called "team1" and "team2".